# Equal distance in \itemize

Tags: itemize

I am using `\itemize` environment to list my quantities. i.e.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item veloity = 20
\item Average velocity = 10
\end{itemize}
```

I dont want to put manual spaces to adjust '=' sign, because my quantity name is longer. Is there any solution or I am too lazy?
Document class is `book`.
Thnx for your time :)
[image]

Comment: `\item velocity${}= 20$`.  Doing it like this *in math mode* will provide the proper *math* spacing around the `=` sign.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes why not putting both `veloity = 20` and `Average velocity = 10` in math mode?

Comment: Hello again, please look into the image I have added. it'll be more clear for you to understand. ty @StevenB.Segletes and manooooh

Comment: Generally, words even in math are typeset upright, not italic.  So `$velocity = 20$` would give proper spacing for the equal, but the word would be typeset in italic as a string of math variables, rather than as a word.  Another way is `$\textrm{velocity} = 20$` which will typeset in math mode spacing, but the word will be typeset as text.

Comment: Your image does not make clear to me your desire...there are no `=` in your image, and there seems to be some sort of tabbing going on to the numbers on the right.  Tabbed space is different than a natural math spacing.

Comment: sorry my mistake. overall i just want the values 947 V, 687 V etc at equal distance after quantity name. so it looks like above image. I think now you are getting me :) ty sir.

Comment: A worse problem is in the minimum value "-631 A", where the "-" is clearly a hyphen when it should be a minus sign.  Putting this expression in math mode would fix that, at the cost of shifting it to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I defined the `AlignedItemize`  enviroment to which you pass in the text that is the widest in that particular list.  The `\MakeBox` then typsets the parameter to the appropriate width.

```
\begin{AlignedItemize}{Average velocity}
  \item $\MakeBox{Velocity} = 20$
  \item $\MakeBox{Average velocity} = 10$
\end{AlignedItemize}
```

yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\WidestText}{}%
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestText}][l]{#1}}

\newenvironment{AlignedItemize}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\WidestText}{#1}%
    \begin{itemize}
}{%
    \end{itemize}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{AlignedItemize}{Average velocity}
    \item $\MakeBox{Velocity} = 20$
    \item $\MakeBox{Average velocity} = 10$
\end{AlignedItemize}
\end{document}%
```

Comment: place of '=' is fixed. if I enter 'average velocity in km/h' then '=' sign is intrersecting along with the quantity name.

Comment: @Mannie: This approach requires that the first parameter of the `AlignedItemize` be the _longest_ string. So, in this case you should use `\begin{AlignedItemize}{Average velocity in km/h}`.  This parameter determines the width of the text.

Comment: thank you peter. its done.

Answer (score 1):

I personally encountered the same problem some time ago (given I have understood your question correctly). At that time, I tried brute force and started using tabulars. It worked for me, as I believe it is a straight forward solution. Hopefully it could be appropriate for you, too.

```
\begin{tabular}{l c l}
Velocity & $=$ & $20$ \\
Average velocity & $=$ & $10$ \\
Fahrdrahtspannung & $=$ & $9$ 
\end{tabular}
```

If you want to use those kinds of tables more often, I suggest you create a new environment for this. In your preamble, put:

```
\newenvironment{conditions}
{\par\vspace{-14pt}\hspace{4pt}\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
{\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

Then, you can use

```
\begin{conditions}
Velocity & $20$ \\
Average velocity & $10$ \\
Fahrdrahtspannung & $9$ 
\end{conditions}
```

to generate this kinds of tables automatically.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that this solution will cause problems if the table cannot fit on the page properly. Further, the spaces that I put in the environment are spaces that worked well for me in a document I created. Of course they can be adapted at your will.

Comment: @Mannie did my solution solve your problem?  If there are still questions about my approach, feel free to ask!

Comment: Yes yours works also. I wanted to stick with itemize because of bullet points. Thankx though. ;)

Comment: It should be easily possible to add a \bullet in a separate column of the defined table/environment. The main thing is that your problem was solved and if the other solution (definitely more elegant) suited you better, that’s great, too!